# Get record from one table where id is in second table array in mysql json

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I have two tables in my MySQL database with the following structure.

```
table roles
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | name      | description         |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Owner     | Owner of a workspace|
|  2 | Biller    | Biller of workspace |
|  3 | Member    | Member of Workspace |
+----+-----------+---------------------+


table user which contain an array of roles id in JSON data type.
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | name      | roles               |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | xyz       | [1,2]               |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Now, table user contains an array of role id, I want to join both tables on the condition, role.id is in user.roles. For example, I want to get some data like this:

select * from roles join user on roles.id in user.roles where user.id=1;

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | name      | description         |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Owner     | Owner of a workspace|
|  2 | Biller    | Biller of workspace |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: add atleast 2-3 rows from each of tables

Comment: *"how can I do this?"* You can start by giving us real example data and expected results.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: why not, create a role table and make an association with user table.. then you can easy check them.

Comment: "table user contains an array of role id".  This is not possible.  MySQL does not have an array type.  Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This works much better

```
select * from roles where FIND_IN_SET(id,(select Replace(Replace(roles,']',''),'[','') from user));
```